# Run shell command from launch script

Tags: ros, shell

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i need to run some system commands ( configurating drivers and similar stuff )
at startup and thought about doing so by including them into the .launch script of my project.

Is this a good idea, is there a simple way to run shell commands ( with root privileges ) from a launch script? Or if not, is there maybe a simple node that i can call to execute shell commands.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33772/run-shell-command-from-launch-script/) by [mapa17](https://answers.ros.org/users/2363/mapa17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mapa17](https://answers.ros.org/users/2363/mapa17/) on 2012-05-11**:
Running the command from a shell script would be nice, but how do i call that script via roslaunch?
That was what i was looking for in the beginning, reading [http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In principle you can put your commands in any shell script, put it in a ROS package and rosrun that or call it via roslaunch.

One thing that might prevent this from being usable is that you don't have a guarantee that your commands are executed before any others (besides executing different launch files).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2